# Passing parameters to the prototype Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following function to create a dimension

```
var Dimension = (function() {

    function Main(a, b) {
        console.log("Main",a ,b)
        return new Elements();
    };

    function Length(a, b) {         // <=(a, b)
        console.log("Length",a ,b)
    };
    Length.prototype = {
        update: function(a, b) {console.log("Length.update", a, b)},
         color: function() {}
    };

    function Angle(a) {
    };
    Angle.prototype = {
        update: function() {},
         color: function() {}
    };

    function Elements() {
    return { length: function(a, b) { return new Length(a, b) },// <=(a, b), <=(a, b)
                  angle: function() { return new Angle() }
               };  
    };

    return Main
})();

var d = Dimension(1,"M");
var dL = d.length(3,"L");
dL.update(5,"LU")
```

I don't like rewriting parameters (a, b) between functions, from the Elements function object, through new to the Length function. Can this code be written differently? I would like to avoid passing an object as a parameter, or using the obsolete "arguments". Is it possible to achieve a cleaner result with Object.create?
Thank you for the answers ... Excuse my English :-)

Comment: Where exactly do want dynamic number of parameters? It's unclear. There are a lot of `(a,b)` in the question

Comment: I added a comment where the same parameters are repeated 3 times

Comment: You can add parameters to `Elements` constructor, pass them from `Main` and use that in `new Length(a, b)`: https://jsfiddle.net/e6ujrkz5/  . Or you can use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and spread the arguments: https://jsfiddle.net/aywjLmvb/

Comment: I like the solution with Rest Parameters, because when refactoring the code I only modify the declaration of the function and its body, while I don't have to solve what is between (fnc Elements and operator new)
Thank you for the sample.